# Cambiar rango de gráfica en ChartJs

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, chart.js

tengo la siguiente gráfica:

[image: ChartJS]

Y mi código es el siguiente:

```
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        // The type of chart we want to create
        type: 'bar',

        // The data for our dataset
        data: {
            //labels: ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio"],
            labels: [
                <?php  
                    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(email) FROM login";
                    $resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
                    while($registros = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
                        ?> '<?php echo $registros['email'] ?>',
                    <?php
                    }                     
                ?>],
            datasets: [{
            label: "Ultimas conexiones",
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(243, 197, 63)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(243, 197, 63)',
            //data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],
            data: [
                <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(email) AS nombre FROM login GROUP BY email";
                    $resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
                    while($registros = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
                        ?> '<?php echo $registros['nombre'] ?>',
                    <?php
                    } 
                ?>
            ],
            }]
        },

        // Configuration options go here
        options: {}
    });
</script>
```

Quisiera modificar el rango y en vez de que vaya de 0.2, se vaya incrementando en 1. ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes utilizar ticks.stepsize asi:

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'bar',

    // The data for our dataset
    data: {
        //labels: ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio"],
        labels: [
            <?php  
                $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(email) FROM login";
                $resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
                while($registros = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
                    ?> '<?php echo $registros['email'] ?>',
                <?php
                }                     
            ?>],
        datasets: [{
        label: "Ultimas conexiones",
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(243, 197, 63)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(243, 197, 63)',
        //data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],
        data: [
            <?php
                $sql = "SELECT COUNT(email) AS nombre FROM login GROUP BY email";
                $resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
                while($registros = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
                    ?> '<?php echo $registros['nombre'] ?>',
                <?php
                } 
            ?>
        ],
        }]
    },

    // Configuration options go here
    options: {                                        
            scales: {
                yAxes: [
                    {
                        ticks: {                                    
                            stepSize: 1  
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
    }
});
```